# SQL OR not returning all rows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm having what may be the dumbest issue.
I'm using phpmyadmin and when I query a table using `OR` it does not return all values.
This is the query that is not returning all values:
`SELECT * FROM ecrdatabase.ecrtable m WHERE m.ecrChangeOwner = '$partialOwner' OR m.ecrInitByName = '$partialOwner'`.
Here, `$partialOwner` is passed from `$_GET['user']`.
Some of the rows are returned - just not all of them. I have a php page that queries the database and I have tried running the query directly on the database through phpmyadmin using query: 
`SELECT * FROM ecrtable WHERE ecrChangeOwner = 'ecunningham' OR ecrInitByName = 'ecunningham'`.
Both results from the the direct query and php page return the same number of rows.
I have also tried:
`SELECT * FROM ecrtable WHERE (ecrChangeOwner = 'ecunningham' OR ecrInitByName = 'ecunningham')`.
What am I missing? I have more complex queries that run fine. Please tell me I'm just missing something stupid...

Comment: *Both results from the the direct query and php page return the same number of rows.* What's the problem then?

Comment: @Manu They're both wrong. The correct number of rows should be 119, but both only return 97. If I run the queries separately 'SELECT * FROM ecrtable WHERE ecrInitByName' returns 32 rows. 'SELECT * FROM ecrtable WHERE ecrChangeOwner' returns 87 rows.

Comment: you know that both queries can return doubles when condition1 and condition2 are match for one row... the last query return all the data from query1 and query2 but without doubles.

Comment: @Manu THAT'S what it is. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: I didn't even think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *really* should be using prepared statements here, first of all.  You are wide open to injection attacks.

Second, how do you know that this query does not return all the rows?  What queries have you done to verify that this one is wrong?

If you run a union what do you get:

```
SELECT * FROM ecrtable WHERE ecrChangeOwner = 'ecunningham'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ecrtable WHERE ecrInitByName = 'ecunningham')
```

Comment: You are both correct. The behavior I was looking for is not possible the way I ran the query. I have duplicates in the two columns. You are also ABSOLUTELY correct about the injection. I have been lazy to try and understand PDO and this is for an internal system at my job (low security). But I still need to understand the important issues. Thanks. I voted for this answer.

Comment: `this is for an internal system at my job (low security)` -> ** famous last words **.  If it is useful, it will not be like this for long and it is 100 times easier to do it right the first time.